# Converting string array to XML in C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I have got two arrays:

```
string[] Countries={"US","India","China","England","Australia"};
string[] States={"Texas","Karnataka","Xinjiang","Birmingham","Canbera"};
```

How do i make a LINQ to XML to present it in this way:

```
<Category>
  <US>Texas</US>
  <India>Karnataka</India>
  <China>Xinjiang</China>
  <England>Birmingham</England>
  <Australia>Canbera</Australia>
</Cateogry>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible way using LINQ [`Zip()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to combine the two arrays into `XElement`s :

```
string[] Countries = { "US", "India", "China", "England", "Australia" };
string[] States = { "Texas", "Karnataka", "Xinjiang", "Birmingham", "Canbera" };
var doc = new XElement("Category",
                       Countries.Zip(States, (c, s) => new XElement(c, s))
          );
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

<kbd>[`Dotnetfiddle Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tOzZnG)</kbd>

**output :**

```
<Category>
  <US>Texas</US>
  <India>Karnataka</India>
  <China>Xinjiang</China>
  <England>Birmingham</England>
  <Australia>Canbera</Australia>
</Category>
```

Comment: Thanks for Dotnetfiddle :) I will use it.